# Where can I get json currency data feeds every millisecond?

Tags: fx, pairs-trading, currency

I have been looking for free or paid json data feeds on currencies for long.

I have come across:

- currencylayer.com
- Oanda
- XE

The problem is that I really need millisecond based updates.

Can someone advice me on the way forward?

Comment: What you require simply doesn't make sense, unless you own a server right next to the one driving the FX exchange in the region you're interested in. Just try to ping any server and you will have a log of at least ~30 ms. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [True FX](http://www.truefx.com/) or open an account with [Interactive Brokers](https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/en/home.php)

Comment: IB batches their quote updates at 250ms intervals, do you get only 4 updates per second.

Answer (score 1):

If you want millisecond updates, you need to use technologies other than json.

Comment: How does a data structure determine the rate of data? Not true at all.

Comment: I suppose he assumed OP want to use some kind of web request, in which case he'd be right.

Answer (score 1):

There are so called mid-rate reference price providers who eventually offer newsfeeds, however, the answer will very likely be a commercial service.

The otehr path would be to contact liquidity providers and / or exchanges directly and ask for API / feed access , which again , will most likely be a commercial service.

Answer (score 1):

https://Polygon.io has FX real-time and historic APIs.

WebSockets for real-time updates, and RESTful API for historic data.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check https://finage.co.uk for Real-time Fx and Stocks API.

APIs works for requests, WebSockets works for Real-Time connection.